# How to add new user event in slack integration with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slack-api

I am trying to add new event for slack integration for get notification when new user register. But my code is not working, Please help

```
add_filter( 'slack_get_events', function( $events ) {
$events['register_form '] = array(
    'action'      => 'register_post',
    'description' => __( 'When new user added', 'slack' ),
    'message'     => function(  ) {
        return sprintf( 'New User created successfully.' );
    }
);

return $events;
} );
```